# What’s the difference between python and python3

Tags: python-3.x

I’m following some instructions to configure my pc to coding some solidity sample projects and the instructions tell me to install pip and pipx, but first I need to check the version of Python installed.  The instructions say to run this at the command prompt:

> python3 --version

but when I do, I get the following error:

> Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.

However, if I run:

> Python --version

It returns:  Python 3.8.5

So when I’m instructed to run “python3” ….  Is that an apple syntax where I would use just “python” for windows?  I’ve googled this and could not find any clarification.

Thank you.

Comment: Python2 (outdated) and python3 can be installed at the same time. On systems that have both versions installed, usually python3 is used to target the python version 3.x.x specifically. python is then used for version2. If your mac only has version3 installed there is no difference by using python to execute your python apps.

Comment: Check the following url please
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61521213/7766792

Comment: Thanks All, but I'm still stuck.  Please not me comment above where I get an error using the "Python3" syntax

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between python and python3 command on Unix prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61521156/what-is-the-difference-between-python-and-python3-command-on-unix-prompt)

Comment: Again, in your case, it doesn't matter whether you run python3 or python when your intended target is python version3.
@SuperStormer this answer was already posted ^^

Comment: Thanks! So to be clear, all I need to do now is run this:
python -m pipx ensurepath

Right?

Comment: From the information we have, i´d say. yes

Answer (score 0):

Often in reading instructions for installing things in Python, we see syntax like this:

```
python3 --version
```

but on my PC I get an error "Cannot find python3"  even though I have python 3.7, 3.8 and 3.9 installed.

For me using this syntax worked:

```
python --version

python -m pip install --user pipx
python -m pipx ensurepath
```