# Difference between $python and $python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my base environment, when I use `Python --version`, I get 3.7.3. When I use `Python3 --version`, I get 3.11.2.

Then next I activate a virtual environment that I previously created with Conda. When I use `Python --version`, I get 3.8.5. When I use `Python3 --version`, I get 3.11.2.

I am wondering which version of Python am I really using when in the virtual environment. I am guessing that the version that the `Python` command is giving me is the actual version of Python I am using in the environment as it is the one that changed after activating my environment, and also it is the one I find in my './anaconda3/envs/virtual_environment' folder. But I would like to be very sure and also I wonder what exactly is the difference between using `Python` and `Python3`.

The other reason why I am curious is this. I was initially downloading a package which required a higher version of Python. At that point, in my environment my `Python --version` was 3.7.3 and `Python3 --version` was less than 3.11.2. I downloaded the stable version of Python 3.11.2 directly from Python website and installed with the .pkg file. Magically, the package which was installed in my environment started working, even though I did not specifically upgrade the Python version in that environment and the Python version it should be using in that environment should still be 3.8.5.

I just want to make sure I understand what version of Python I am really using, for the sake of scientific rigor...

I am aware that a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61521156/what-is-the-difference-between-the-python-and-python3-commands-in-unix-like-syst) asked the same question and the answer suggested was that Python was for Python 2. However, I am not sure how it is applicable in my case since both commands give me versions of Python 3. Unless there is some deeper link to Python 2, which then was not explained in the older post.

Comment: It can easily become a mess. The surest way is just to activate the virtualenv and type `python` to enter the interpreter, and see what it tells you there

Comment: Generally, you *create* the virtual environment using the version of Python you want/need. Don't try to reuse an existing venv that wasn't expressly created for your project.

Comment: Python 2 was discontinued so `Python was for Python 2` is no longer true. The meaning of `python` and `python3` depends on Python was installed so *don't* leave things to chance, use a virtual environment. `Python3` was a useful shortcut when Python 2 was still supported

Comment: @roganjosh thank you for the suggestion! this confirms my suspicion that Python is the command that is giving me the actual version that I am using in each environment. However, I wonder what is Python3 really giving me then, especially since downloading the latest version of python (just casually into my main mac OS) somehow fixed an error that was within the environment.

Comment: I foobar'd my python versions on my first mac (coming from windows) and part of it (I at least think) was through installing Anaconda. From that learning, I just used `homebrew` for my new system as I got confused about the different aliases that were set up

Comment: @roganjosh I realised that if I type Python3 to enter the interpreter I will enter version 3.11 instead (even though it is in the environment), which kind of makes sense since those were the commands that gave their respective versions. So I am guessing somehow my environment has two versions of Python. Then the headache next is which version is my IPykernel using... because I am using Jupyter lab in the environment, so how do I tell for sure which version of Python is my kernel running on...

Comment: Try going from the other direction; `python3 -m pip install virtualenv` and then `python3 -m virtualenv definitely_311` (choose a snazzier name for the second command), both outside of a virtualenv. That should pin it to 3.11, and then you can link it to your jupyter instance. Then you have `source definitely_311/bin/activate`

Comment: @roganjosh yes, the nuclear option is to rebuild my environment and avoid Conda to be sure. Thanks for your suggestions nonetheless!

Comment: The nuclear option would be to remove them all (somehow) and start again. I settled for certainty when I messed up my first environment and it kinda worked. But telling you "just live with it" is a poor answer, sorry

Comment: @roganjosh it is nonetheless good to know that I am not missing something glaring!

Comment: What do the dollar signs mean in the title?

Comment: @mkrieger1 i meant it to be commands to avoid any misunderstanding that I was asking about the difference between Python 2 vs Python 3.

Comment: Are you sure that the commands are capitalized? And if you use e.g. `which python` or `which python3`, does this output what you are looking for?

Comment: @mkrieger1 apologies, you are right, they should be lower case. Your suggestion is very interesting. ```which python``` shows a path through anaconda3 and ```which python3``` shows a path through /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3. I think this again confirms that the environment is using the version from ```python --version```, but the question remains why upgrading the Python in the Frameworks folder resolved an error in my environment where it should use its own version of Python.